# Integral of Gaussian Distribution

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the below integral and my idea is to substitute $x$ by $\sqrt[]{t}x$. And my final answer is $\sqrt[]{t}$. But my textbook shows that the result should be $t$. Could someone explain where I did wrong? Thank you very much.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[]{2\pi}*t}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2t})dx$$

I think the original statement is like this: For a random variable with probability density for x at time t give that $f(x,t) = $
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\pi}*t}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2t})$$
And it says that $E(x(t)^2) = t$. I'm not sure whether I misunderstand something.

Comment: Well, t should be $\sqrt{t}$ according to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result looks correct to me

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} x^2 e^{-x^2/(2t)}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}t=\sqrt{t}   $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{split}\frac{1}{\sqrt t} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\sqrt t}\exp{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx&=\frac{1}{\sqrt t} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f_{N(0,t)}(x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt t}E(X^2)\end{split}$$

with $X\sim N(0, t)$

$E(X^2)=var(X)+[E(X)]^2=t+0=t$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt t}(t)=\sqrt t$$